# Dropdown - How to transfer a list of 4000 words from excel to the dropdown menu in my code?

Tags: excel, dropdown

I have a list of 4000 words in excel which I want to have in a dropdown menu on the website. I don't want to do it the hard way by listing each, one by one, but at the same time I also couldn't find any relevant information on how to do it? May be some smart people can really help me out here. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't.  A single drop down of 4000 values isn't a good use for a drop down; from a user experience standpoint.  Performance will be bad on load/reload; a user will not likely scroll through a list of 4000 items.  (show me a good site using over 100!  Usual limit is # of countries/states so < 100 on average.)https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/how-many-items-in-a-web-form-drop-down-is-too-many

Answer (score 0):

A drop down list in HTML is like:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

So write out, by hand, your `<select>` and `</select>`. Then next to each cell containing text just do (Assuming text in cell `A1`)

```
="<option value=""" & A1 & """>" & A1 & "</option>"
```

Copy down to all your text values and paste into your HTML document.